# Why doesn't Google+ auto upload all my pictures consistently and in the right sequence?

Tags: backup, photos, google-plus, google-plus-photos

Google+ doesn't upload my photos consistently, and sometimes it uploads them out of order.

Why would the app not do its job consistently? There are missing pictures, and then a week later they randomly show up (sometimes, sometimes not), and sometimes out of sequence, which is very frustrating.

If I uninstall and reinstall Google+, will it have to reload the last 4 years of pictures? Or worse, lose my pictures from my old droid that died? I have plenty of storage space left (several GB).

It is a new Samsung S5 phone, but I have the same problem on the old Droid Razor. Auto upload is enabled, and if I try the "upload now" option, it tells me everything is already uploaded, when I can clearly see I am missing pictures.

Comment: Fwiw I'm having the exact same problem. Auto backup says it's all done when there are clearly some photos not in the backups.

Comment: I know when using G+ to look at the photos make sure to select View All, I think it defaults to Highlights. 

Also you can view them all via google drive. You should have a folder called Google Photos. I notice from time to time. Photos that dont show up on G+ are in my drive under that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you choosed "Only WiFi" when the app asked you if you want to upload photos via wifi, mobile or both... 
Try clearing G+'s data and restarting the settings step from zero...
I had a similar problem with a S4 and this was the problem/solution ;)

Comment: There is also an option for only when charging, check that too!
Also is your sync always enabled? As far as I know the google+ photo's will only back up when sync is enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can access the site of Plus (plus.google.com) and see if your photos are ok. If everything is fine, you can even reset your phone and your photos will be safe. After check your photos on the site, you can try to uninstall and reinstall the app. Maybe it solve the problem.